# Get rid of top/bottom margin/padding on C3 Chart

Tags: javascript, css, c3.js

I have a few charts which I'm trying to fit snuggly into a div. I can't seem to make the top/bottom white space go away. Ideally the top of the graph and the bottom legend would fit snuggly against the div. Any ideas? I've tried the padding options, but they don't seem to affect that specific white space.

http://jsfiddle.net/264v700x/5/

```
var chart = c3.generate({
        padding: {
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0
        },
        data: {
          json: [{
            date: '2014-02-02',
            download: 100,
            total: 500
          }],
        keys: {
          x: 'date',
          value: ['why']
        }
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
          type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
              format: function (x) {
                if (x.getDate() === 1) {
                        return x.toLocaleDateString();
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

CSS/JS hacks welcome! I'd like it to fit the div and not have to specify a height, but if specifying a height is the only way, I can work around it.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**
I went through c3.js and it looks like this is being added in the javascript somewhat statically. I'll have to refactor the code to work around this.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else wondering - this space comes from these lines of code in c3's code:

```
$$.margin = config.axis_rotated ? {
    top: $$.getHorizontalAxisHeight('y2') + $$.getCurrentPaddingTop(),
    right: hasArc ? 0 : $$.getCurrentPaddingRight(),
    bottom: $$.getHorizontalAxisHeight('y') + legendHeightForBottom + $$.getCurrentPaddingBottom(),
    left: subchartHeight + (hasArc ? 0 : $$.getCurrentPaddingLeft())
} : {
    top: 0+ $$.getCurrentPaddingTop(), // for top tick text
    right: hasArc ? 0 : $$.getCurrentPaddingRight(),
    bottom: xAxisHeight + subchartHeight + legendHeightForBottom + $$.getCurrentPaddingBottom(),
    left: hasArc ? 0 : $$.getCurrentPaddingLeft()
};
```

You can either manually adjust it, or add code to allow for zero margin situations.